# Is it a must to provide "sign in with apple" if we provide a "sign in with microsoft" Azure Active Directory. in our iOS App?

Tags: ios, azure-active-directory, saml, sign-in-with-apple

[4.8 Sign in with Apple](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#sign-in-with-apple)

According to the guideline above, we must provide "sign in with apple" if we're providing a 3rd party mean of authentication.

Except if "Your app is an education, enterprise, or business app that requires the user to sign in with an existing education or enterprise account." and some other cases.

My question is; If using MSAL to authenticate with Azure Active directory is considered using a 3rd party authentication method, or it'd be exempted as it's an enterprise account?

We need to support MSAL to one of our clients, and trying to figure out whether "sign in with apple is mandatory"

Answer (score 0):

As I read it you have to use Sign in with Apple in your case. Here is the official text from the [guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#sign-in-with-apple):

> Apps that use a third-party or social login service (such as Facebook Login, Google Sign-In, Sign in with Twitter, Sign In with LinkedIn, Login with Amazon, or WeChat Login) to set up or authenticate the user’s primary account with the app must also offer Sign in with Apple as an equivalent option. A user’s primary account is the account they establish with your app for the purposes of identifying themselves, signing in, and accessing your features and associated services.

Comment: How about Except if "Your app is an education, enterprise, or business app that requires the user to sign in with an existing education or enterprise account." Is a user on Azure Active Directory considered an enterprise account or not? That's the vague part, at least for me.

Comment: I would interpret it like: if you need to access services of MS Azure AD then you don't need that. This rule is made to generate traffic for Sign in with Apple (SIWA) when you want to give users the choice between multiple providers but don't really require one of them. Also when your potentially make an app for your employees where they have to sign in with MS then you don#t need SIWA.